# Error while quantizing transformer in Pytorch

Tags: machine-learning, pytorch, quantization

```
input = torch.randn(2, 6, 1024)
t = torch.randn(2)

print(model_static_quantized(input, t))
```

Gives this error

```
NotImplementedError: Could not run 'quantized::linear' with arguments from the 'CPU' backend. 
This could be because the operator doesn't exist for this backend, or was omitted during the selective/custom build process (if using custom build). 
If you are a Facebook employee using PyTorch on mobile, please visit https://fburl.com/ptmfixes for possible resolutions. 
'quantized::linear' is only available for these backends: [QuantizedCPU, QuantizedCUDA, 
BackendSelect, Python, FuncTorchDynamicLayerBackMode, Functionalize, Named, Conjugate, Negative, ZeroTensor, ADInplaceOrView, AutogradOther, AutogradCPU, AutogradCUDA, AutogradXLA, AutogradMPS, AutogradXPU, AutogradHPU, AutogradLazy,
 Tracer, AutocastCPU, AutocastCUDA, FuncTorchBatched, FuncTorchVmapMode, Batched, VmapMode, FuncTorchGradWrapper, 
PythonTLSSnapshot, FuncTorchDynamicLayerFrontMode, PythonDispatcher].
```

`model_static_quantized` is defined by post-training static quantization. It is a quantized version of a transformer defined in this paper by OpenAI: https://arxiv.org/pdf/2212.08751.pdf, with QuantStub and DeQuantStub added to the start of the

Comment: I have the same error, did you find what the issue was ?